# Show $|A + uv^T| = (1 + v^T A^{-1} u) |A|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A$ be an invertible square matrix. Prove that
>
> $$
> |A + uv^T| = (1 + v^T A^{-1} u) |A|.
> $$

---

**My attempt**

$|A + uv^T| = \left|A (I + A^{-1}uv^T)\right| = |A| |I + A^{-1} uv^T|$

I'm trying to use the following fact,

$$(I + ab^T)^{-1} = I - \frac{1}{1+b^T a}ab^T$$

but it seems quite tricky because of the $A^{-1}$ part.

Comment: See [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). This question has probably been asked here before but I could not find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. For the last step, letting $w:=A^{-1}u$, note $I+wv^T$ has eigenvalues $(1, 1, \dots, 1+v^T w)$. So 
$$\det(I+A^{-1}uv^T) =\det(I + w v^T) = 1 \times \dots \times (1+v^T w) = (1+v^TA^{-1}u).$$